# how to make the text in a div to not overflow its width

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with the following css

```
.divTab
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 550px;
    overflow:scroll;
    font-size: small;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

and the following html

```
  <div id="fragment-1">
        <div class="divTab">
            <pre>'.$my_name.'</pre>
            <pre>'.$my_servings.'</pre>
            <pre>'.$my_clients.'<pre>
            <pre>'.$my_description.'<pre>
        </div>
   </div>
```

So now my problem is that the text being brought by `$my_description` overflows the width and adds a scroll at the bottom, i do not want it to overflow its width but instead break into the next line if it reaches the divs width. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
pre {
    overflow-x: auto; /* Use horizontal scroller if needed */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space : normal;
}
```

Here's an example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/cSa2C/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:scroll;` from your code.

Comment: But i do want it to overflow vertically if the height is past the divs size,my problem is the width..- Actually if i do that, the text just gets out of the whole div and is all messed up

Comment: Ahhh try replacing it with overflow-x: auto; instead

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a `<pre>` tag is that it is "preformatted text", displayed in a fixed width, and only conservating the layout you put in it manually. It hence expects you to do the layout yourself(say, add `<br />`'s. You can, as answered above, alter the functionality of the `<pre>`, or consider not using them and instead use, for example, a regular `<div>`.